# Text inputs with 'X' icon to clear the field once you start typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Search inputs are styled with pill-shaped corners and adds an "x" icon to clear the field once you start typing.

Can I do the same for regular text boxes? See the fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/nvWnx/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `data-type="search"` to the text input, and it will receive the same style as the search box, but that will also include the magnifying glass, here are some option:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvWnx/9/)

A little fiddling around, came up with this:

[**FIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvWnx/12/)

Comment: Yeah this is much simpler solution. didn't think of the data attribute. You can reduce the parent `div`'s `paddingLeft` if you don't want those 30px blank on the left.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - good idea, would look something like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nvWnx/16/)...

Comment: Yup awesome. `=]` I was struggling with the bgcolor too if removing the `ui-icon-searchfield` which I fixed by setting the background-size to 0 instead of removing the class and setting the bg-color, but the end result is the same. Awesome and simple answer man. `=]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `val()` method for clearing values of *regular* inputs.

```
$('#X').click(function(){
   $(this).prev().val("").focus();
   // $(this).remove()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvWnx/3/

- [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it inside a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.addClearButton = function(width) {
        if (typeof width === 'undefined') width = '50%';
        this.wrap('<div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-c"></div>').bind('input keyup', function() {
            $(this).next().css('display', ($(this).val() !== '') ? 'inline-block' : 'none');
        }).parent().css({backgroundSize: '0 0', paddingLeft: 10, width: width}).append($('<a title="clear text" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" href="#" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>').click(function() {
            $(this).hide().prev().val('').focus();
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);

//the width parameter is optional.
$('#basic').addClearButton(200);
//integers are treated as px, can accept % and em between quotes too e.g. '77%'
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/nvWnx/18/)

Note that it will mimic the Search button's markup, that is, wrapping the input in a `div` to place the X button floated at the right of the input.

If you upgrade the jQuery from 1.6.2 to 1.7+, replace the `.bind` by `.on`.

Edited to remove the search icon.

Added optional width parameter.

Comment: Thanks, making it a plugin is a good idea. However, the magnifying glass on the left, is sth I don't want. It is actually why I want to use text field instead of a search. Is there any chance to hide it?

Comment: @noway I didn't notice it at first, just removed it now. `=]`

Comment: I would +1, but you should really be providing the 1.7.2 solution - jQuery 1.8 is out, people should not be using 1.6 any more.

Comment: I wish I could accept this as an answer too. However, @adeneo's solution was really simple.

Comment: @CallumMacrae this works perfectly fine in 1.7/1.8 thanks to their back-compat. @ noway No problem, I agree Adeno's solution is (+1 to him) simpler and doesn't require so much extra code.

Comment: @CallumMacrae, Fabricio refer to 1.6 because it is the version I used in fiddle. Actually, I am not also using 1.6 neither.

Comment: Exactly. `=]` The jQuery mobile version in the fiddle would have to be updated too to work with jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  $.fn.clearable = function() {
    var $this = this;
    $this.wrap('<div class="clear-holder" />');
    var helper = $('<span class="clear-helper">&times;</span>');
    $this.parent().append(helper);
    $this.parent().on('keyup', function() {
      if ($this.val()) {
        helper.show();
        helper.css('display', 'inline-block');
      } else helper.hide();
    });
    helper.click(function() {
      $this.val("");
      helper.hide();
    });
    $this.on('focus', function() {
      helper.show();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);


  $('#myInput').clearable();
```

```css
.clear-holder{
    position:relative;
    float:left;  
}
.clear-helper{
    margin-top:4px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    right:4px;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
    background:#e0e0e0;
    border-radius:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text"/>
```